# Using write.xlsx inside of a for in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very big database called *"Duplicados_2010_2022*" and I want to generate excel files disagreggated by a specific column. I want to subset the database by the column "*SECRETARÍAS*", because I need to see the data by each secretary (they  are 92). I tried using the following expression:

```
Lista  <- levels(as.factor(Duplicados_2010_2022$SECRETARÍA))
for (i in Lista) {
  write.xlsx(Duplicados_2010_2022[Duplicados_2010_2022$SECRETARÍA==i,],i)
}
```

The problem is that when I asigned *i* as the file name, it does not include the *.xlsx*, therefore it exports the file, but not as an excel file.
If somebody could suggest me a way for not doing the export 92 times, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try with `paste0(i, ".xlsx")`

Comment: FYI, it _is_ an excel file, it's just that Windows relies heavily on the extension. As a repair effort, you could also do `ign <- mapply(file.rename, Lista, paste0(Lista, ".xlsx"))` (ignoring the return value).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
for (i in Lista) {
  write.xlsx(paste0(Duplicados_2010_2022[Duplicados_2010_2022$SECRETARÍA==i,], ".xlsx"), i)
}
```

The first argument of function `write.xlsx` is the file name, and the ".xlsx" extension was missing in the file name string. It must be specified.

Comment: Yes! it perfectly worked with paste().